# Irregular grid from dataframe to raster in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grid, geospatial, raster

I have extracted data at points (lat& lon) at irregular interval. Can a irregular grid be created from the extract dataframe? I do not intend to interpolate the data and keep as it is.
I am getting an error trying to create a gridded dataset-

```
      lon     lat   temp
1  8.5261 50.0223 293.40
2 78.4390 17.2290 295.90
3  8.6350 49.9290 282.88
spg <- df
coordinates(spg) <- ~ lon + lat
gridded(spg) <- TRUE
```

Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `round` the values

```
library(sp)
spg[1:2] <- lapply(spg[1:2], function(x) as.numeric(round(x)))
coordinates(spg) <- ~ lon + lat
gridded(spg) <- TRUE
```

-output

```
> spg
Object of class SpatialPixelsDataFrame
Object of class SpatialPixels
Grid topology:
    cellcentre.offset cellsize cells.dim
lon                 9       69         2
lat                17       33         2
SpatialPoints:
  lon lat
1   9  50
2  78  17
3   9  50
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA 

Data summary:
      temp      
 Min.   :282.9  
 1st Qu.:288.1  
 Median :293.4  
 Mean   :290.7  
 3rd Qu.:294.6  
 Max.   :295.9
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(lon = c(8.5261, 78.439, 8.635), lat = c(50.0223, 
17.229, 49.929), temp = c(293.4, 295.9, 282.88)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If we would like to precisely plot the points, where a milimeter change can affect the results. In that case, will it be possible to work without rounding it off in "function(x) as.numeric(round(x))".

Comment: @Dipu Can you try adding `digits` in `round` for precision

Comment: Thanks for your much needed help. df does creates the grid. But when it comes to long list of coordinates (in 1000s) instead of just three as example, how to list all coordinates (in thousands) in structure(list(lon =..."2',"3")) ? Suppose we would like to list by the columns of lat, lon, temp.

Comment: @Dipu You meant the structure.  It is just with `dput` function.  i.e. `dput(head(iris))`